# Read file and save as double array, then write it as new file

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing this homework where I am supposed to read a `.txt` file filled with integers into a `double` array, and then write this double array into another `.txt` file.

At first I thought everything was working as I was able to read the file and display it out as an image, and then save it into a `.txt` file as `double`s. However, when I tried to use the same class file for another lesson (display it in frame I created), I kept getting `0.0` as the value of the output `.txt` file. Below is the code for my read and write class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class IO {
  FileDialog fd;
  public double[][] readData() {
    fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Open Files", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    File f = null;
    if ((fd.getDirectory() != null)||( fd.getFile() != null)) {
      f = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
    }
    FileReader fr = null;
    try {
      fr = new FileReader (f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int lines = -1;
    String textIn = " ";
    String[] file = null;
    try {
      while (textIn != null) {
        textIn = br.readLine();
        lines++;
      }
      file = new String[lines];
      fr = new FileReader (f);
      br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        file[i] = br.readLine();
      }
      br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    double[][] data = new double [lines][];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(file[i],",");
      data[i] = new double[st.countTokens()];
      int j = 0;
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
        j++;
      }
    }
    return data;
  }


  public void writeData(double[][] dataIn) {
    fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save Files", FileDialog.SAVE);
    fd.setVisible(true);
    File f = null;
    if ((fd.getDirectory() != null)||( fd.getFile() != null)) {
      f = new File(fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile());
    }
    FileWriter fw = null;
    try {
      fw = new FileWriter (f, true);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
    String tempStr = "";
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < dataIn.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataIn[i].length; j++) {
          tempStr = String.valueOf(dataIn[i][j]);
          bw.write(tempStr);
        }
        bw.newLine();
      }
      bw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The txt file I am trying to read have 300 rows and column, of which not all column are filled to full with int number. I could get the input txt to be Display but could not save it back as a txt file with the same values but in double instead of int.

Could someone help me out here please?

Comment: Please indent your code properly!

Comment: Sorry about the indent, had updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your complete problem, but you have at least the problem that you forget to add a comma after each number when you write to the file. Since `readData` uses commas to separate numbers, files produced by your program cannot be read by it. Simply change

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataIn[i].length; j++) {
          tempStr = String.valueOf(dataIn[i][j]);
          bw.write(tempStr);
```

to

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataIn[i].length; j++) {
          bw.write(String.valueOf(dataIn[i][j]) + ",");
```

(removed the intermediate `tempStr` since it is unnecessary as your code is now).

Comment: Hi Niklas, I tried your method but doesn't seems to work. It still give me a result of 0.0 with no "," as delimiter at all in the output txt file.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you - I actually tried it myself and I get commas in the output file.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question - precisely what is wrong? Illustrate with the output file (and for which input it is produced), for example.

Comment: Hi Niklas, main problem I am facing is not been able to get save an output txt file with the same value as the input file but in double instead of int. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Again, can you show us what you get in output file, and for which input?

Comment: hmm I tried to include a image but was rejected as I just am new and just sign up less than a day ago. Anyway below is the link to the screen shot I took. Left image is what I am suppose to get, right is what I am getting now from my frame.
http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/2259/pic1ip.png

Comment: Hi @Niklas Lönnerfors, think I manage to get it done, not sure if it is correct tho. Thanks for your help. Just signed up here so am curious as I am now stuck at another part of the code, is it ok if I post the new "chock" point here or I should start a new question?

Comment: You should start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had manage to get this sorted, not sure if it is the right way tho. Below is what I added before the try catch loop to write data:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
dataIn = getData(dataIn);
try {
```

I created a getData(double[][] data) method in the Class so I could now read the data in.

Comment: `dataIn` is passed as a parameter to `writeData`, this should not be necessary. How do your call `writeData`? Post the code.